# MySQL Cant update table in stored trigger because its already used by statement which invoked this trigger

Tags: php, mysql, триггер

Здравствуйте.
Проблема собственно в заголовке.
есть три таблички, с зависимостью 1 ко многим:
apps.id
└─versions.app_id
└─translations.app_id

Когда добавляются или удаляются строки из нижних двух таблиц, меняется запись в соответствущем поле таблицы apps.
триггер (для примера, *translations after delete*)

```
BEGIN
UPDATE apps SET translations_count = translations_count - 1 WHERE apps.id = OLD.app_id LIMIT 1;
END
```

триггер (*apps before delete*)

```
BEGIN
DELETE FROM app_info_translations WHERE app_info_translations.app_id = OLD.id;
DELETE FROM app_versions WHERE app_versions.app_id = OLD.id;
END
```

Когда удаляю запись из apps, триггер удаляет записи из зависимых таблиц, которые, в свою очередь пытаются модифицировать эту самую запись в apps (и тут возникает ошибка).

**Вопрос**: как перестроить базу, оставив тот-же функционал, но избавиться от ошибки? Т.е. с возможностью удалить запись из apps

> p.s. триггеры добавлены для хранения статистики в записях таблицы
>   apps, вместо постоянной выборки разной информации из кучи таблиц.

Comment: А если триггер на апдейт так же сделать before. он же тогда попытается отработать когда записи в верхней таблице уже не будет и апдейтить будет нечего. хотя хз конечно. И триггер на удаление из дочерних таблиц можно попробовать убрать и вместо него foraign ключи в дочерних таблицах сделать on delete cascade

Comment: но on delete cascade не запускают триггеры. Хотя в принципе логично, что при удалении и строка и все зависимости в других таблицах не будут иметь значения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо Mike за совет.
Т.К. почти все "статистические" данные о связанных записях других таблиц хранятся в удаляемой строке из apps - логично их удалять не триггером, с изменением данных "в ручную" а просто on delete cascade.